# Utility that can be configured to run two commands, and kill both when one finishes

Tags: process-management

Is there a common utility (Ubuntu, perhaps OSX) that can run a server `serve ./public`, then run some tests `./run-chrome-tests.sh`, and once the tests are finished, kills the `serve ./public`.

This can be done in bash, but I'd rather create configuration, than code if it is feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is to my knowledge no such utility, but it is easily implemented in a shell script.

A short shell script that implements what you described:

```
#!/bin/sh

serve ./public & serve_pid=$!
./run-chrome-tests.sh

kill "$serve_pid"
```

You may want to insert a `sleep 3` call (or similar) after starting `serve` in the background, to allow it to initialize properly before running the testing script.

`$!` will be the PID of the most recently started background job (the `serve` process).  When the `run-chrome-tests.sh` script finishes, the script above will explicitly terminate the `serve` process by signalling using `kill`.

Comment: Ah, that is even simpler than the bash I had envisioned...very nice. Accepted because this is what I'll end up doing even though it wasn't exactly what i asked for.